# javascript keyup to change divs not just text

Tags: javascript, keyup

I have some code that checks if 2 text fields match. This is using the keyup which works fine but I would like it to hide or show a div depending on result. All I have is a code that changes divCheckPasswordMatch?

So I would like it to

```
$('#match').hide();
$('#nomatch').show();
```

The js code is :

```
 $(function() {
    $("#password2").keyup(function() {
        var password = $("#password1").val();
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(password == $(this).val() ? "Passwords match." : "Passwords do not match!");
    });
});
```

Comment: make a if(_condition_) hide()

Comment: example and where to put it please?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to have two `<div>` displaying different messages using `show()` and `hide()`, but I'm not sure, so I did both.

```js
$('#match').hide();
$('#nomatch').hide();

$("#password2").keyup(function() {
  var password = $("#password1").val();
  
  
  if ($(this).val() === password) {
    $('#divCheckPasswordMatch').html('Passwords match');
    $('#match').show();
    $('#nomatch').hide();
  } else {
    $('#divCheckPasswordMatch').html('Passwords do not match');
    $('#match').hide();
    $('#nomatch').show();
 }
  
  
});
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First input: <input id="password1" type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Second input: <input id="password2" type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></div>
<div id="match">Match</div>
<div id="nomatch">No Match</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well following what you want you can do this.

HTML

```
<input id="password1">
<input id="password2">
<spam id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></spam>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
    $("#password2").keyup(function() {
        var password = $("#password1").val();
        var password2 = $("#password2").val();
        if(password!== null && password2!== null){
            if(password == password2) {
            $('#divCheckPasswordMatch').show();
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.")
          }
          else {
            $('#divCheckPasswordMatch').hide();
            $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!")
          }
        }
    });
});
```

But remember that you also need to anticipate if the password1 is changed too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example. For learning purposes I highly suggest using pure javascript instead of jQuery. It is easy to rewrite it to jQuery. I can do it for you if you want.

You are missing blur event, I've added it. Code is not repeatable, it can be still improved. We are using one function for validation.

```js
 var field1 =  document.getElementById('password1');
 var field2 =  document.getElementById('password2'); 
 var result = document.getElementById('divCheckPasswordMatch');
 
 function validateInputs() {
  // If any of fields is empty then quit
  if (field1.value === '' || field2.value === '') {
    return;
  }
  
  if (field1.value === field2.value) {
    result.innerHTML = '';
    // optional hide it, clearing text gives almost the same effect, up to you
    // result.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = 'Passwords don\'t match';
    // optional show it
    //result.style.display = 'block';
  }
 }
 
 document.getElementById('password1').addEventListener('keyup', validateInputs);
 document.getElementById('password2').addEventListener('keyup', validateInputs);
 
 document.getElementById('password1').addEventListener('blur', validateInputs);
 document.getElementById('password2').addEventListener('blur', validateInputs);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password1">
<input type="text" id="password2">
<div id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></div>
```